# Android recycvler view layout mismatch between preview and actual layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm working on my graduation work and prior to including custom toolbar (for hamburger icon) and replacing ListView with NavigationView for DrawerLayout menu items I've had no problems with layouts at all. This is the preview from AS and the desired, expected result with RecyclerView[image: Preview in android studio]

and that is the actual view on the Android device (LeTV X800 API21 if that matters at all)
[image: Actual view]

As you can see the gap between consecutive items is huge and I don't know what is the source of the problem. I'm using a single activity which xml contains frame container where desired layouts are loaded.
fragment_car_cost.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/car_cost_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/space"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/car_cost_entry_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/space"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_car_cost">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/car_cost_floating_action_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_fab_label="Opcje"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/car_cost_entry_recycler_view">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_car_costs_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        fab:fab_label="@string/add"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_car_costs_statistics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
        fab:fab_label="@string/statistics"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_car_costs_charts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        fab:fab_label="@string/charts"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and recycler view item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/car_cost_header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="7sp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/car_cost_entry_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cost_type_image_view"
            android:layout_width="75sp"
            android:layout_height="75sp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
            android:longClickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_cost_entry_date_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cost_type_image_view"
            android:text="17.08.2017 17:20"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car_cost_entry_date_text_view"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cost_type_image_view"
            android:text="Typ: paliwo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/car_cost_entry_type_text_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Koszt: 666,66zł"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car_cost_entry_type_text_view"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cost_type_image_view"
            android:id="@+id/car_cost_entry_cost_text_view"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cost_details_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post layout file of recyclerview item.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Already edited the question but I've made no changes to the item layout since very long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content` in `RecyclerView` Item layout

```
<LinearLayout ...
            ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    ... >
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I feel dumb right now to have missed such an obvious problem. Just out curiosity why did it even work prior to modifications?

Comment: You might have tried it with `ListView`, but with `RecyclerView` height should be `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` is useless in `RecyclerView` item row. Just remove the parent `LinearLayout` and let the `CardView` be root element. This way, code become more optimized and also resolve your problem.